# Bluetooth Scan does not work properly after I publish the app

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

1. I'm creating an app that communicates with an IOT board via Bluetooth low energy. When I install the app for testing directly from my pc it works perfectly. But when I published it, it doesn't list the Bluetooth devices.
2. I am using the following permissions
3. android.permission.INTERNET
4. android.permission.BLUETOOTH
5. android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
6. android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
   'These permissions are in'
   'android/app/src/main/androidManifest.xml'
   'android/app/src/profile/androidManifest.xml'
   I'm using the ble component: ^2.0.0

Comment: Which flutter library are you using? Which Android version is your phone using? Please check wether or not the permissions you declared are actually granted by going to your phones settings -> apps

Comment: my library is BLE.
link https://pub.dev/packages/ble
android version: 29
the problem is that when I install the app from my machine in a test environment it works perfectly. However when I publish it the description of the bluetooth device does not appear.  The app has all permissions accepted